# Can gradient descent fail for convex functions?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, gradient-descent

Let $U$ be an **open** convex subset of $\mathbf{R}^n$ and $f:U\rightarrow\mathbf{R}$ be a differentiable and convex function. We assume that $f$ has a unique global minimum $x^\star$ over $U$. It is well-known that if $\nabla f$ is $L$-Lipschitz then for any $x_0\in U$ the sequence
$$x_{n+1}=x_n - L^{-1}\nabla f(x_n) $$
converges to $x^\star$. I would like to know whether the Lipschitz condition is necessary.

Specifically, I am looking for a counterexample. Is it possible to find $U$ and $f$ such that for some $x_0\in U$ and any $\eta>0$ the gradient descent
$$x_{n+1}=x_n-\eta\nabla f(x_n)$$
does not converge to $x^\star$?

For example, I would be very interested to see if there exists a counterexample with $\nabla f$ uniformly continuous over $U$.

Comment: [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1508031/2947) to a related question seems quite relevant.

Comment: @BobPego thanks a lot, this answer is indeed relevant. My understanding is that they show a $(x_0, \eta)$ pair such that there is no convergence. However, fixing $x_0$, some $\eta>0$ does work. I am looking for a counterexample where fixing $x_0$, no $\eta>0$ works.

Comment: If $f$ does not have a Lipschitz continuous gradient (a.k.a. it is a non-smooth function), it is well-known that the gradient descent algorithm won't converge to $x^\star$ in general, unless we use diminishing step-sizes. For example, let $f(x) = |x|$. Unless $x_0$ and $\eta$ are chosen such that some gradient descent iterate lands exactly at $x_{n+1} = 0$, they will keep bouncing around the minimizer, for any $\eta >0$.

Comment: This algorithm is known to converge for fixed step-sizes, $\eta\in\left]0,2/L\right[$. A counterexample would require the stepsize outside of this range.

Comment: @durdi yes, thank you. However, the absolute value function is not differentiable at zero so this is not exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Zim what is $L$ in your example? If the gradient is not $L$-Lipschitz I don't think that this work.

Comment: $L$ would be the Lipschitz constant of the gradient. I was thinking of just demonstrating that *even for smooth functions*, GD might not converge (e.g., if we take a stepsize too big there is no guarantee). However, I now see that you want a setting for which this fails for every $\eta$, so that sort of example wouldn't exactly answer your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the example from the linked answer can be modified to fit your bill "fix $x_0$, no $\eta > 0$" works.

First, we note that the example cannot be one-dimensional. Indeed, you can always choose $\eta$ such that $x_1$ is already the minimizer.

In two dimensions, I think that the following should work. Define
$$
f(x,y) = \frac23 (x^2 + 2 y^2)^{3/4}
$$
and choose $(x_0, y_0) = (1,1)$. It seems that no $\eta$ gives you convergence. I guess that it is also not hard to prove this.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. My issue is that $f$ is not differentiable at zero, so it's not exactly what I'm looking for. This is a very nice example however, which can be made even simpler by considering $z\mapsto |z|^{0.75}$ in $\mathbf{C}$. It's very easy to see that the gradient descent sequence diverges for any $\eta>0$ by working in polar coordinates.

Comment: I don't see why $f$ is not differentiable. We have $f(x,y) \le C (|x|+|y|)^{3/2}$, thus $f'(0,0) = (0,0)$. And with your example $z \mapsto |z|^{\text{something}}$, you have the problem that for every initial $z_0$ there is one step size $\eta$ such that the first iterate $z_1$ is precisely $0$, i.e., the method is convergent.

Comment: This function $f$ nicely answers OP's question, that is, whether the Lipschitz condition on the gradient of $f$ is necessary. Namely, $f$ is differentiable, but does not have a Lipschitz continuous gradient, which is precisely the reason the gradient descent algorithm does not converge with a constant step size $\eta$.